# incluir input em vetor de nomes e apresentar

Tags: javascript

estou fazendo um exercício de javascript, nele se pede que adicione o nome de um input em um vetor de caracteres. Esse vetor já esta apresentado e conforme eu aperto em adicionar ele vai crescendo na tela os nomes. Fiz esse código mas não obtive sucesso. Podem me dar uma força? Agradecido desde já.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" id="btn" name="nome">
        <button onClick="adicionar()">adicionar</button>
        <ul id="lista">

        </ul>
    
    
    </div>

<script>
    function adicionar(){
        var text = document.querySelector('#btn')
        var conteudo = text.value
        nomes.push(conteudo)
    }

   var lista = document.querySelector('#lista')
   var nomes = ["Diego", "Leonardo", "João"]
    for(var i=0; i< nomes.length;i++)
    {
        var item = document.createElement('li')
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nomes[i]));
        lista.appendChild(item)
    }


</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entao amigo, foi um pouco dificil de enteder o proposito do codigo, pela minha concepção, dado um vetor contendo nomes, deve-se criar um elemento para cada nome, e no botão adicionar, adiciona novos nomes nesse vetor certo?
Nesta parte em especifico:

```
for(var i=0; i< nomes.length;i++)
{
    var item = document.createElement('li')
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nomes[i]));
    lista.appendChild(item)
}
```

O que acontece é que, quando o browser carrega a pagina, ele passa por todo esse codigo, incluindo este for somente UMA vez.
Sendo assim o seu codigo ele adiciona o nome no vetor, porem não cria e adiciona os itens, para resolver isso eu coloquei o for em uma função.

```
function atualizaNomes(){
   for(var i=0; i< nomes.length;i++)
   {
       var item = document.createElement('li')
       item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nomes[i]));
       lista.appendChild(item)
   }
   nomes = [];
```

Note que eu coloquei `nomes = []` no final para que ele limpe o array para caso voce clique de novo.
Para chamar essa função criei um simples botao com `onclick`

```
<button onclick="atualizaNomes()">Atualizar nomes</button>
```

Esse problema também pode ser resolvido criando os elementos e adicionando eles na lista dentro da função `adicionar()`

Para lidar com strings vazias você pode adicionar isso

```
if(nomes[i] == "" || nomes[i] == " " ){
    continue
}
```

No caso, se nomes[ i ] for uma string vazia ou uma string com um espaço ele ira pular a iteração da estrutura de repetição (Adicione esse if dentro do for)
Espero que você entenda e eu tenha ajudado, qualquer outra duvida só responder aqui mesmo. Boa sorte ae campeão! :)

Comment: eu consegui fazer funcionar com suas dicas. Muito obrigado Ricardo e desculpe me a má elaboração.

Comment: Tudo bem, tenta sempre elaborar a questão com o maximo de informação e tenta explicar o proposito melhor, qualquer só lançar no site dnv :)